# Why is my cell nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am writing the code to populate a UITableView from using a CoreData database wrapped in magical record. For some reason though the code docent seem to be working and my cell is considered nil. Why is this happening?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    PassWhizEntity *pazz = [allPasses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = pazz.destinationTeacherAttribute;
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:pazz.dateAttribute];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"cell was nil");
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

it just prints cell was nil and loads a blank UITable. Any ideas?

Comment: [`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:) returns `nil` when there are no reusable-cells in the queue, so this is the correct behaviour :) (to add some context to the below answer...)

Comment: @Rich Note that that's only true if you are not using prototype cells and storyboards and/or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` any of which is the preferred mechanism to use as of iOS 6.0.

Comment: @David Yep along with the newer `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"cell was nil");
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    PassWhizEntity *pazz = [allPasses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = pazz.destinationTeacherAttribute;
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:pazz.dateAttribute];

    return cell;
}
```

You are trying to set `textLabel` of unallocated cell which have no effect on cell. Cell is returned nil because tableview don't have any cell that can be reused, so it is your responsibility to check for nil and make new Cell if needed.

Comment: The question asked "why" `cell` is `nil`. While this shows the proper code, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Jesse, it depends. If you create cell prototypes in your storyboard, or use `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` then what you say is correct. However, it is still possible to not do any of those things and have your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method create cells directly through code if the no recycled cell is returned from the dequeue method

Comment: In that case which `init` method is called ?

Comment: @Jesse for efficiency the OP should also be using [`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:), but they cannot as they are not registering a class. There is nothing with the above approach.

Comment: @jesse You're partially correct.  You can use the newer registerClass and/or registerNib mechanisms to get cells more automatically created for you, but you can still use the old-school approach as well.  Particularly in a case like this where you're using a stock UITableViewCell, I'd opt for the explicit check and create as well.

Comment: @jesse You've made the "performs better" claim a couple of times now.  Do you have references for that, or is it just an opinion?

Comment: Or if you are targeting (shudder) iOS 5 then the old way is the only way. But a note, you can do `[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];` if you like...!

Comment: Anyway I still think downvoting this answer which is perfectly correct (now the extra info has been added) is wrong. But that's my opinion.

Comment: @Jesse you are wrong with your registering the class statement working on iOS 5 - [`registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:) was not introduced till iOS 6.